# in review is not there in app status, But I can't publish my app in playstore

Tags: android, apk

I uploaded two apps on playstore at the same day. The first app that i've uploaded got verified. But the second one, showed in review. And it's now gone. But I can't publish or it is not showing any other things.
[The second app status (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDQGT.png)

and inside of release overview it Available to testers on Google Play Full roll out

[The release overview screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIVtA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're uploading your app to closed testing track which means that the app will only be available to the google accounts which you have specified in the testers list.

To rollout an app to everyone on google play, you'll have to upload your app to production. This page https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859348?hl=en gives a good explanation of how to prepare and rollout a release.

You can also simply promote your current release to production and that will move the same apk from closed testing to production track. Once it's reviewed by google, it'll be available to everyone on playstore.

Comment: It's going under review again. I will let you know after the process has been finished